# Swifty JSON not working with iOS Game project, but working as Single View Application project

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to access a simple JSON using SwiftyJSON. As a Single View iOS Application, the following works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let test = [ "turn" : "5", "row" : "1", "column" : "2" ]
    let json = JSON(test)
    println(json)

    var turn: String = ""
    turn = json["turn"].stringValue
    println("swifty json .stringValue turn = \(turn)") // correctly prints "swifty json .stringValue turn = 5"

    if let turn = json["turn"].string {
        println("swifty json .string turn = \(turn)") // correctly prints "swifty json .string turn = 5"
    }

}
```

The terminal output is:

> {
>     "column" : "2",
>     "turn" : "5",
>     "row" : "1"
>   }
>
> swifty json .stringValue turn = 5
>
> swifty json .string turn = 5

Yet when I create a fresh project starting as an iOS Game, it no longer works.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let test = [ "turn" : "5", "row" : "1", "column" : "2" ]
    let json = JSON(test)
    println(json)

    var turn: String = ""
    turn = json["turn"].stringValue
    println("swifty json .stringValue turn = \(turn)") // prints "swifty json .stringValue turn = "

    if let turn = json["turn"].string {
        println("swifty json .string turn = \(turn)") // never gets here because turn is nil or null
    }
```

The terminal output is:

> {
>    "column" : "2",
>   "turn" : "5",
>   "row" : "1"
>   }
>
> swifty json .stringValue turn =

How does one access JSON when using SwiftyJSON in an iOS Game? I am using Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3.

Comment: Still you can't access JSON when using SwiftyJSON in an iOS Game? I would like to help if you need.